# Why must I use shell to run named binary in Docker?

Tags: docker

Working with alpine in docker and trying to start named but it only exits (with zero output)

This works
`CMD /usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf`

and is then represented in the docker image as

```
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "/usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf"
```

However this does NOT work.

`CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-c /etc/bind/named.conf"]`

Here's the full Dockerfile, I also use it for CI Test

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add bind bind-tools bash
CMD /usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing arguments for the command.

With `CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-c /etc/bind/named.conf"]`, the program sees it as:

```
argc = 3
argv[1] = "-f"
argv[2] = "-c /etc/bind/named.conf"
```

However using a shell, because the shell does parameter splitting for you, the actual command is:

```
argc = 4
argv[1] = "-f"
argv[2] = "-c"
argv[3] = "/etc/bind/named.conf"
```

So you probably should write the Dockerfile like this:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The CMD command has three variants:

1. exec form: `["executable", "param1", "param2"]`
2. parameters for ENTRYPOINT: `["param1", "param2"]`
3. shell form: `executable param1 param2`

The second one is only valid if `ENTRYPOINT` is specified in the image. The dirrerence between the first and third one is that the exec form does not run shell and shell form does.

In other words `CMD /usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf` on Alpine actually runs `/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf"` and is therefore equivalent to `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/sbin/named -f -c /etc/bind/named.conf"]`, which why both work.

As for `CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-c /etc/bind/named.conf"]` it passes TWO arguments to `named`: `-f` and `-c /etc/bind/named.conf`, when clearly you want to pass THREE arguments: `-f`, `-c` and `/etc/bind/named.conf`.

You should try `CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-f", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf"]`. It will probably work as I do not think that `named` requires the shell.

See also [Dockerfile reference for CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)